# Wordnet Similarity 4 Java (WS4J)

Tags: java, similarity, wordnet, ws4j

I'm working on a project where one of its requirements is to calculate the similarity between words. I'm using WuP measure to calculate the similarity between the words which supposed to return values between [0,1]. The problem is that the jar file seems to have bugs where it doesn't return values in this range. The [web page demo](http://ws4jdemo.appspot.com/?mode=w&s1=&w1=java%23n%233&s2=&w2=java%23n%233) works perfectly where for identical words it returns the maximum value 1 but the jar file doesn't return the same. The results for `run( "java","java" );` is:

```
run:
edu.cmu.lti.ws4j.impl.HirstStOnge   1.7976931348623157E308
edu.cmu.lti.ws4j.impl.LeacockChodorow   1.7976931348623157E308
edu.cmu.lti.ws4j.impl.Lesk  1.7976931348623157E308
edu.cmu.lti.ws4j.impl.WuPalmer  1.7976931348623157E308
edu.cmu.lti.ws4j.impl.Resnik    1.7976931348623157E308
edu.cmu.lti.ws4j.impl.JiangConrath  1.7976931348623157E308
edu.cmu.lti.ws4j.impl.Lin   1.7976931348623157E308
edu.cmu.lti.ws4j.impl.Path  1.7976931348623157E308
Done in 8 msec.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

The problem is not only with identical words, even for different words it gave wup valueout of the range:

The webpage demo :

```
wup( avocado#n#1 , fruit#n#1 ) = 0.9091
jcn( avocado#n#1 , fruit#n#1 ) = 0.5974
lch( avocado#n#1 , fruit#n#1 ) = 2.5903
lin( avocado#n#1 , fruit#n#1 ) = 0.8982
res( avocado#n#1 , fruit#n#1 ) = 7.3837
path( avocado#n#1 , fruit#n#1 ) = 0.3333
lesk( avocado#n#1 , fruit#n#1 ) = 203
hso( avocado#n#1 , fruit#n#1 ) = 6
```

Jar file values:

```
run:
edu.cmu.lti.ws4j.impl.HirstStOnge   6.0
edu.cmu.lti.ws4j.impl.LeacockChodorow   2.5902671654458267
edu.cmu.lti.ws4j.impl.Lesk  6.0
edu.cmu.lti.ws4j.impl.WuPalmer  1.0526315789473684
edu.cmu.lti.ws4j.impl.Resnik    7.383733213970693
edu.cmu.lti.ws4j.impl.JiangConrath  0.5973799749775183
edu.cmu.lti.ws4j.impl.Lin   0.8981855517382724
edu.cmu.lti.ws4j.impl.Path  0.3333333333333333
Done in 1673 msec.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Could someone help how to fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

1.7976931348623157E308 is the maximum double number.
It is as if it represents infinite, because the two words are identical.

Try "hi" and "hello" and it returns 1.0